# How do I run "npm run watch" on specific address and port? (Laravel mix)

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-mix, npm-start

How can I run **npm watch** with a specific url and port?

In my package.json file I have following the line

```
"watch": "mix watch",
```

in the scripts section, which works fine with the command **npm run watch** and is accessed via localhost. I would like to access it at http://dev.myproject:8888 instead of localhost, as I have a number of projects.

To run **npm start** with a specific local url is can add the following line to the "scripts" section of my projects package.json :

```
"start": "http-server -a dev.myprojectname -p 8888"
```

(in order to this one must add dev.myprojectname to your "hosts" file, connected to 127.0.0.0)

How can I specify the same for **npm watch** ?

I have tried the same under watch ie :

```
"watch": "http-server -a dev.myprojectname -p 8888"
```

but this is not correct

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled upon the same question, so I will answer for posterity.

To pass args directly to webpack, `-- --port <PORT>` did the trick.

```
    "watch": "mix watch --hot -- --port 3080",
```

Hope it helps someone ;)